# Problem w/ Migrate Source CSV importing Body content w/ HTML

Tags: migrations

I am using migrate_source_csv to import node body fields. The header for my CSV file is: "nid, title, body". The body fields contain HTML. My problem is that, on import, the HTML is being encoded into literals. See the screen grab below. Here is my migration YML file:

```
id: news_article_nodes
label: News article data we want.
migration_group: gdg_group
source: 
  plugin: csv
  path: 'modules/custom/gdg_migration/import/news_article/news_articles.csv' 
  ids: [nid]
  header_row_count: 1
process:
  nid: nid
  title: title
  'body/0/value': body
  'body/0/format':
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: full_html
destination: 
   plugin: entity:node
   overwrite_properties:
     - body
   default_bundle: news_article
```

I must be missing something. Is there a plugin that imports the data as plain text?

[image: screen shot of node body w/ encoded HTML]

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use PHP's `html_entity_decode()` on the source field:

```
process:
  nid: nid
  title: title
  body/value: 
    plugin: callback
    callable: html_entity_decode
    source: body
  body/format:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: full_html
```

PS: You've written that your source CSV doesn't contain encoded entities... have you checked the display settings for your field? (`Manage > Structure > Content types > NODE_TYPE > Manage display`). It could be that the import is correct, but the render settings are incorrectly set to something like plain text or a `|raw` filter in a Twig template file.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but same result.   Interestingly, I am having this problem on Windows.  I tried the same development environment on a Mac and it displays the HTML correctly.  I am still  trying to debug on Windows.

Answer (score -1):

you have just to remove de /0/ from body field

```
 body/value: body
 body/format:
  plugin: default_value
  default_value: full_html
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I am getting the same result.

Comment: When I view source I can see that < is replaced with &lt;, > w/ &gt;, etc.  This is not in the CSV file.  Some thing is filtering the HTML on import.